# Can one feasibly calculate the Glicko rating of a player by just using a pen, a paper and a calculator?

Tags: rating, glicko, glicko-2

I calculate the informal Elo ratings of a small pool of players (~10-15 in number) of whom I'm a member, using a scientific calculator.

Can I do the same with the Glicko rating system, *feasibly*? (I'd prefer the Glicko-2 system, but even the original Glicko would do.)

#### Note

If it isn't possible, could someone name some online or offline program by which I could do that?

Comment: There is also a tool for calculating it now: https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/39167/19880

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it is possible! All the functions needed for the calculations are available on a scientific calculator, e.g. square root, log, value for pi, etc.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system) should get you started.
[Mark Glickman's page on the system](http://www.glicko.net/glicko.html) should take you further.

This pdf has detailed descriptions and equations for Glicko-2 - http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko2.pdf.

Javascript code for implemeting Glicko-2 is available here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/glicko2.

> I've edited the question to make my implication clear: is it feasible to calculate the Glicko rating with the assistance of a scientific calculator?

Back in 1983 when I was working on the lateral guidance team for the flight management and control system for the Airbus A310 I used 2 programmable calculators, the HP15C and the HP16C to generate test data. These Glicko algorithms could be programmed into those calculators using 38 year old technology. I don't know what calculator you have nor what your programming skills are but for a competent programmer with a reasonably good 20th century programmable calculator it should be straightforward.