# Is there any (free) online tool for calculating Glicko-2 ratings after a game?

Tags: software, rating, glicko-2

I am looking for a tool where I can input the Glicko-2 ratings of 2 players and the result of the match (1–0, 0–1 or draw). Also, the rest of the Glicko-2 parameters, i.e., each player’s rating deviation and volatility (σ), and the system constant (τ). Then, the tool will tell me what the ratings of the players will be after the match (and their new rating deviation and volatility).

There are already similar free online tools for Elo. E.g., [Elo Calculator by Omni Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/sports/elo).

I am aware of code implementations of this, as well as an Excel calculator, but I am looking for an online GUI tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now published in [streamlit share](https://share.streamlit.io/fsmosca/glicko2calculator/main/glicko2calculator.py)

##### Calculation #1

[image]

##### Calculation #2

[image]

Comment: It looks fantastic. I'm no expert but it looks correct to me. But I suggest you try the example in the Glicko-2 PDF: http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko2.pdf (end of page 4)

Comment: The library I am using was already tested with that pdf and the result is the same.